# Using different IDs for multiple table in SQLITE

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am using SQLite to work on an android application. What I have learned so far is that a table made in SQLite requires a column called _id. So, for instance, to create a table, I use the following SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Semesters(
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
semester_name TEXT,
is_current TEXT
GPA REAL);
```

However, now if I want to create a seperate table in the same database, what would I name the primary key column? For instance, this is the table I want to create:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Classes(
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
course_name TEXT);
```

Now, both the semesters table and the courses table have a column called _id, and if I want to make a foreign key reference to the _id column in the semesters table, I will have to call it by the table name. Is there any way to make this simpler by using different names for ids?

Thanks.

Comment: Simpler than what? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you make a third table and want to use both primary keys from your tables as foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE ClassSemester(
_id INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
semester_id   INTEGER, 
class_id      INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(semester_id) REFERENCES Semesters(_id),
FOREIGN KEY(class_id) REFERENCES Classes(_id)
);
```

More details in here:
http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html